# trading in the limelight for a different kind of light altogether

Tags: meaning

I saw translation of this, but the end part of the sentence is translated just as 'for someting else' not in details. What does 'trading in the limelight for a different kind of light altogether' mean?

> So what was it that made him run at the height of his career and throw
>   it all away, trading in the limelight for **a different kind of light
>   altogether**?

Comment: We can't say what this "different kind of light" might be without more context.  What is the source?

Comment: Would you please stop referring to things you do  not explain? It is becoming annoying. You claimed the other question was a translation, when in fact you misheard something. So, you seem to be referring to translated sub-titles we can't see or that are not in English, and mishearing the actual English. This is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic expression:

to be in the limelight. Meaning: to be at the center of things. It is viewed as positive.

The origin is theatrical lighting in early theaters prior to electric lighting.

[limelight in theaters or dance halls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limelight)

A different kind of light could be any number of things: **to be seen in a bad light**, another idiom,for example. Or whatever the context suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the light was, it was nothing like limelight, which refers figuratively to fame, to being in the public eye, hearkening back to the day when the performance stage was lit by lights which used the chemical "lime".

> He had been riding a mountain bike but decided to get **a different kind of bike altogether**, opting for a commuting bike with small wheels, one that could be folded up and taken on a train.

The word "altogether" means "entirely" or "in virtually all respects".

He opted to get a bike that was *entirely* different from the one he had.

He opted to get a bike that was different *in virtually all respects* from the one he had.

The word **altogether** can come before the adjective:

> ... an altogether different kind of bike

or

after the noun-phrase:

> ... a different kind of bike altogether